# HTML Form Submit button is not working on Mobile devices

Tags: html

I am newbie in this field and in learning stage, I created a HTML form it working great on Desktop and PC. But when i go to mobile devices and talblet the form **submit button** is not working. Can anybody help me on this. Please see the code below.

```html
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: Please add the following <META> element to your page <HEAD>.      -->
<!--  If necessary, please modify the charset parameter to specify the        -->
<!--  character set of your HTML page.                                        -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Register Your Interest</title>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
                color: #FF0000;
}
</style>

</head>

<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: Please add the following <FORM> element to your page.             -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<body>
<center>
<form action="https://cs85.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

<input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D6E000000D1aw">

                
<input type="hidden" name="debugEmail" value="jishad.mohamed@reedexpo.ae">  


<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://www.energyefficiencyexpo.com/">
<input type=hidden name="recordType" value="012200000009ANN">
<!--  RX Industry  -->
<input type=hidden name="00N20000001SJtF" value="Other">
<!--  Zip/Postal Code  -->
<input type=hidden name="00N20000001PeCx" value="-">
<input type=hidden name="lead_source" value="Web to Lead">
<!--  Data Source  -->
<input type=hidden name="00N20000001kiBU" value="Register Your Interest">
<!--  Interest -->
<input type=hidden name="00N20000001Pe42" value="ENEF">



<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: These fields are optional debugging elements. Please uncomment    -->
<!--  these lines if you wish to test in debug mode.                          -->
<!--  <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1>                              -->
<!--  <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail"                                  -->
<!--  value="jishad.mohamed@reedexpo.ae">                                     -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->


<!--
<tr> <td> </td><td width="5"> </td> <td> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> </td><td width="5"> </td> <td> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> </td><td width="5"> </td> <td> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> </td><td width="5"> </td> <td> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> </td><td width="5"> </td> <td> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> </td><td width="5"> </td> <td> </td> </tr>

-->
<table style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size:14" >
<tr> <td> First Name:<span class="auto-style1">* </span>  </td><td width="5"> </td> <td align="left" style="width: 400px"> <input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" style="width: 250px" required/><br> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> Last Name:<span class="auto-style1">* </span>   </td><td width="5"> </td> <td align="left" style="width: 400px"> <input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" style="width: 250px" required/><br></td> </tr>
<tr> <td> Title:       </td><td width="5"> </td> <td align="left" style="width: 400px"> <input  id="title" maxlength="40" name="title" size="20" type="text" style="width: 250px" /><br> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> Company:<span class="auto-style1">* </span>     </td><td width="5"> </td> <td align="left" style="width: 400px"> <input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" style="width: 250px" required /><br></td> </tr>
<tr> <td> Email:<span class="auto-style1">* </span>       </td><td width="5"> </td> <td align="left" style="width: 400px"> <input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="email" style="width: 250px" required/><br></td> </tr>
<tr> <td style="height: 26px"> Phone:<span class="auto-style1">* </span>       </td> <td width="5" style="height: 26px"> </td> <td align="left" style="width: 400px; height: 26px;"> <input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" style="width: 250px" required/><br></td> </tr>
<tr> <td> Mobile:</td><td width="5"> </td> <td align="left" style="width: 400px"> <input  id="mobile" maxlength="40" name="mobile" size="20" type="text" style="width: 250px" /><br></td> </tr>
<tr> <td> City:</td><td width="5"> </td> <td align="left" style="width: 400px"> <input  id="00N20000001PeDN" maxlength="120" name="00N20000001PeDN" size="20" type="text" style="width: 250px" /><br></td> </tr>
<tr> <td>Sector:</td><td width="5"> </td> <td align="left" style="width: 250px"> <select style="width:250px; !important; min-width: 250px; max-width: 250px;" id="Sectors__c" name="Sectors__c" title="Sectors">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="ENEF-Building Env&Material Conduct Perf">Building Envelop and Materials Conductive Performance</option>
<option value="ENEF-Efficient Power Generation">Efficient Power Generation</option>
<option value="ENEF-Elevators and Escalators">Elevators and Escalators</option>
<option value="ENEF-Energy Eff. Building Eng. Prod&Sol">Energy Efficient Building Engineering Products and Solutions</option>
<option value="ENEF-Energy Monitoring Systems">Energy Monitoring Systems</option>
<option value="ENEF-Financial and Building Services">Financial and Building Services</option>
<option value="ENEF-Glazing-Reduced Heat Gain Coeff.">Glazing with Reduced Heat Gain Coefficient</option>
<option value="ENEF-High Efficiency Lighting">High Efficiency Lighting</option>
<option value="ENEF-HVAC Equipment and Systems">HVAC Equipment and Systems</option>
<option value="ENEF-Intelligent Building Management">Intelligent Building Management</option>
<option value="ENEF-Lighting Controls">Lighting Controls</option>
<option value="ENEF-Reduce-Cooling Demand-Passive Strat">Reduced Building Air Leakage Rates</option>
<option value="ENEF-Reduced Building Air Leakage Rates">Reduction of the Cooling Demand Using Passive Strategies</option>
<option value="ENEF-Service Water Heating">Service Water Heating</option>
<option value="ENEF-Smart Grids">Smart Grids</option>
</select><br></td> </tr>

<tr> <td style="height: 26px"> Country:</td><td width="5" style="height: 26px"> </td> 
 <td align="left" style="width: 250px; height: 26px;"> <select style="width:250px; !important; min-width: 250px; max-width: 250px;" id="00N20000001PeDG" name="00N20000001PeDG" title="Country">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="AFGHANISTAN">AFGHANISTAN</option>
<option value="ALAND ISLANDS">ALAND ISLANDS</option>
<option value="ALBANIA">ALBANIA</option>
<option value="ALGERIA">ALGERIA</option>
<option value="AMERICAN SAMOA">AMERICAN SAMOA</option>
<option value="ANDORRA">ANDORRA</option>
<option value="ANGOLA">ANGOLA</option>
<option value="ANGUILLA">ANGUILLA</option>
<option value="ANTARCTICA">ANTARCTICA</option>
<option value="ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA">ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA</option>
<option value="ARGENTINA">ARGENTINA</option>
<option value="ARMENIA">ARMENIA</option>
<option value="ARUBA">ARUBA</option>
<option value="AUSTRALIA">AUSTRALIA</option>
<option value="AUSTRIA">AUSTRIA</option>
<option value="AZERBAIJAN">AZERBAIJAN</option>
<option value="BAHAMAS">BAHAMAS</option>
<option value="BAHRAIN">BAHRAIN</option>
<option value="BANGLADESH">BANGLADESH</option>
<option value="BARBADOS">BARBADOS</option>
<option value="BELARUS">BELARUS</option>
<option value="BELGIUM">BELGIUM</option>
<option value="BELIZE">BELIZE</option>
<option value="BENIN">BENIN</option>
<option value="BERMUDA">BERMUDA</option>
<option value="BHUTAN">BHUTAN</option>
<option value="BOLIVIA">BOLIVIA</option>
<option value="BOSNIA AND HERZEGOVINA">BOSNIA AND HERZEGOVINA</option>
<option value="BOTSWANA">BOTSWANA</option>
<option value="BOUVET ISLAND">BOUVET ISLAND</option>
<option value="BRAZIL">BRAZIL</option>
<option value="BRITISH INDIAN OCEAN TERRITORY">BRITISH INDIAN OCEAN TERRITORY</option>
<option value="BRUNEI DARUSSALAM">BRUNEI DARUSSALAM</option>
<option value="BULGARIA">BULGARIA</option>
<option value="BURKINA FASO">BURKINA FASO</option>
<option value="BURUNDI">BURUNDI</option>
<option value="CAMBODIA">CAMBODIA</option>
<option value="CAMEROON">CAMEROON</option>
<option value="CANADA">CANADA</option>
<option value="CAPE VERDE">CAPE VERDE</option>
<option value="CAYMAN ISLANDS">CAYMAN ISLANDS</option>
<option value="CENTRAL AFRICAN REPUBLIC">CENTRAL AFRICAN REPUBLIC</option>
<option value="CHAD">CHAD</option>
<option value="CHILE">CHILE</option>
<option value="CHINA">CHINA</option>
<option value="CHRISTMAS ISLAND">CHRISTMAS ISLAND</option>
<option value="COCOS (KEELING) ISLANDS">COCOS (KEELING) ISLANDS</option>
<option value="COLOMBIA">COLOMBIA</option>
<option value="COMOROS">COMOROS</option>
<option value="CONGO">CONGO</option>
<option value="CONGO, THE DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE">CONGO, THE DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE</option>
<option value="COOK ISLANDS">COOK ISLANDS</option>
<option value="COSTA RICA">COSTA RICA</option>
<option value="COTE D&#39;IVOIRE">COTE D&#39;IVOIRE</option>
<option value="CROATIA">CROATIA</option>
<option value="CUBA">CUBA</option>
<option value="CURACAO">CURACAO</option>
<option value="CYPRUS">CYPRUS</option>
<option value="CZECH REPUBLIC">CZECH REPUBLIC</option>
<option value="DENMARK">DENMARK</option>
<option value="DJIBOUTI">DJIBOUTI</option>
<option value="DOMINICA">DOMINICA</option>
<option value="DOMINICAN REPUBLIC">DOMINICAN REPUBLIC</option>
<option value="ECUADOR">ECUADOR</option>
<option value="EGYPT">EGYPT</option>
<option value="EL SALVADOR">EL SALVADOR</option>
<option value="EQUATORIAL GUINEA">EQUATORIAL GUINEA</option>
<option value="ERITREA">ERITREA</option>
<option value="ESTONIA">ESTONIA</option>
<option value="ETHIOPIA">ETHIOPIA</option>
<option value="FALKLAND ISLANDS (MALVINAS)">FALKLAND ISLANDS (MALVINAS)</option>
<option value="FAROE ISLANDS">FAROE ISLANDS</option>
<option value="FIJI">FIJI</option>
<option value="FINLAND">FINLAND</option>
<option value="FRANCE">FRANCE</option>
<option value="FRENCH GUIANA">FRENCH GUIANA</option>
<option value="FRENCH POLYNESIA">FRENCH POLYNESIA</option>
<option value="FRENCH SOUTHERN TERRITORIES">FRENCH SOUTHERN TERRITORIES</option>
<option value="GABON">GABON</option>
<option value="GAMBIA">GAMBIA</option>
<option value="GEORGIA">GEORGIA</option>
<option value="GERMANY">GERMANY</option>
<option value="GHANA">GHANA</option>
<option value="GIBRALTAR">GIBRALTAR</option>
<option value="GREECE">GREECE</option>
<option value="GREENLAND">GREENLAND</option>
<option value="GRENADA">GRENADA</option>
<option value="GUADELOUPE">GUADELOUPE</option>
<option value="GUAM">GUAM</option>
<option value="GUATEMALA">GUATEMALA</option>
<option value="GUERNSEY">GUERNSEY</option>
<option value="GUINEA">GUINEA</option>
<option value="GUINEA-BISSAU">GUINEA-BISSAU</option>
<option value="GUYANA">GUYANA</option>
<option value="HAITI">HAITI</option>
<option value="HEARD ISLAND AND MCDONALD ISLANDS">HEARD ISLAND AND MCDONALD ISLANDS</option>
<option value="HOLY SEE (VATICAN CITY STATE)">HOLY SEE (VATICAN CITY STATE)</option>
<option value="HONDURAS">HONDURAS</option>
<option value="HONG KONG">HONG KONG</option>
<option value="HUNGARY">HUNGARY</option>
<option value="ICELAND">ICELAND</option>
<option value="INDIA">INDIA</option>
<option value="INDONESIA">INDONESIA</option>
<option value="IRAN, ISLAMIC REPUBLIC OF">IRAN, ISLAMIC REPUBLIC OF</option>
<option value="IRAQ">IRAQ</option>
<option value="IRELAND">IRELAND</option>
<option value="ISLE OF MAN">ISLE OF MAN</option>
<option value="ISRAEL">ISRAEL</option>
<option value="ITALY">ITALY</option>
<option value="JAMAICA">JAMAICA</option>
<option value="JAPAN">JAPAN</option>
<option value="JERSEY">JERSEY</option>
<option value="JORDAN">JORDAN</option>
<option value="KAZAKHSTAN">KAZAKHSTAN</option>
<option value="KENYA">KENYA</option>
<option value="KIRIBATI">KIRIBATI</option>
<option value="KOREA, DEMOCRATIC PEOPLE&#39;S REPUBLIC OF">KOREA, DEMOCRATIC PEOPLE&#39;S REPUBLIC OF</option>
<option value="KOSOVO">KOSOVO</option>
<option value="KUWAIT">KUWAIT</option>
<option value="KYRGYZSTAN">KYRGYZSTAN</option>
<option value="LAO PEOPLE&#39;S DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC">LAO PEOPLE&#39;S DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC</option>
<option value="LATVIA">LATVIA</option>
<option value="LEBANON">LEBANON</option>
<option value="LESOTHO">LESOTHO</option>
<option value="LIBERIA">LIBERIA</option>
<option value="LIBYA">LIBYA</option>
<option value="LIECHTENSTEIN">LIECHTENSTEIN</option>
<option value="LITHUANIA">LITHUANIA</option>
<option value="LUXEMBOURG">LUXEMBOURG</option>
<option value="MACAO">MACAO</option>
<option value="MACEDONIA, THE FORMER YUGOSLAV REPUBLIC OF">MACEDONIA, THE FORMER YUGOSLAV REPUBLIC OF</option>
<option value="MADAGASCAR">MADAGASCAR</option>
<option value="MALAWI">MALAWI</option>
<option value="MALAYSIA">MALAYSIA</option>
<option value="MALDIVES">MALDIVES</option>
<option value="MALI">MALI</option>
<option value="MALTA">MALTA</option>
<option value="MARSHALL ISLANDS">MARSHALL ISLANDS</option>
<option value="MARTINIQUE">MARTINIQUE</option>
<option value="MAURITANIA">MAURITANIA</option>
<option value="MAURITIUS">MAURITIUS</option>
<option value="MAYOTTE">MAYOTTE</option>
<option value="MEXICO">MEXICO</option>
<option value="MICRONESIA, FEDERATED STATES OF">MICRONESIA, FEDERATED STATES OF</option>
<option value="MOLDOVA, REPUBLIC OF">MOLDOVA, REPUBLIC OF</option>
<option value="MONACO">MONACO</option>
<option value="MONGOLIA">MONGOLIA</option>
<option value="MONTENEGRO">MONTENEGRO</option>
<option value="MONTSERRAT">MONTSERRAT</option>
<option value="MOROCCO">MOROCCO</option>
<option value="MOZAMBIQUE">MOZAMBIQUE</option>
<option value="MYANMAR">MYANMAR</option>
<option value="NAMIBIA">NAMIBIA</option>
<option value="NAURU">NAURU</option>
<option value="NEPAL">NEPAL</option>
<option value="NETHERLANDS">NETHERLANDS</option>
<option value="NETHERLANDS ANTILLES">NETHERLANDS ANTILLES</option>
<option value="NEW CALEDONIA">NEW CALEDONIA</option>
<option value="NEW ZEALAND">NEW ZEALAND</option>
<option value="NICARAGUA">NICARAGUA</option>
<option value="NIGER">NIGER</option>
<option value="NIGERIA">NIGERIA</option>
<option value="NIUE">NIUE</option>
<option value="NORFOLK ISLAND">NORFOLK ISLAND</option>
<option value="NORTHERN MARIANA ISLANDS">NORTHERN MARIANA ISLANDS</option>
<option value="NORWAY">NORWAY</option>
<option value="OMAN">OMAN</option>
<option value="PAKISTAN">PAKISTAN</option>
<option value="PALAU">PALAU</option>
<option value="PALESTINIAN TERRITORIES">PALESTINIAN TERRITORIES</option>
<option value="PANAMA">PANAMA</option>
<option value="PAPUA NEW GUINEA">PAPUA NEW GUINEA</option>
<option value="PARAGUAY">PARAGUAY</option>
<option value="PERU">PERU</option>
<option value="PHILIPPINES">PHILIPPINES</option>
<option value="PITCAIRN">PITCAIRN</option>
<option value="POLAND">POLAND</option>
<option value="PORTUGAL">PORTUGAL</option>
<option value="PUERTO RICO">PUERTO RICO</option>
<option value="QATAR">QATAR</option>
<option value="REUNION">REUNION</option>
<option value="ROMANIA">ROMANIA</option>
<option value="RUSSIAN FEDERATION">RUSSIAN FEDERATION</option>
<option value="RWANDA">RWANDA</option>
<option value="SAINT BARTHELEMY">SAINT BARTHELEMY</option>
<option value="SAINT HELENA">SAINT HELENA</option>
<option value="SAINT KITTS AND NEVIS">SAINT KITTS AND NEVIS</option>
<option value="SAINT LUCIA">SAINT LUCIA</option>
<option value="SAINT MARTIN">SAINT MARTIN</option>
<option value="SAINT PIERRE AND MIQUELON">SAINT PIERRE AND MIQUELON</option>
<option value="SAINT VINCENT AND THE GRENADINES">SAINT VINCENT AND THE GRENADINES</option>
<option value="SAMOA">SAMOA</option>
<option value="SAN MARINO">SAN MARINO</option>
<option value="SAO TOME AND PRINCIPE">SAO TOME AND PRINCIPE</option>
<option value="SAUDI ARABIA">SAUDI ARABIA</option>
<option value="SENEGAL">SENEGAL</option>
<option value="SERBIA">SERBIA</option>
<option value="SEYCHELLES">SEYCHELLES</option>
<option value="SIERRA LEONE">SIERRA LEONE</option>
<option value="SINGAPORE">SINGAPORE</option>
<option value="SLOVAKIA">SLOVAKIA</option>
<option value="SLOVENIA">SLOVENIA</option>
<option value="SOLOMON ISLANDS">SOLOMON ISLANDS</option>
<option value="SOMALIA">SOMALIA</option>
<option value="SOUTH AFRICA">SOUTH AFRICA</option>
<option value="SOUTH GEORGIA AND THE SOUTH SANDWICH ISLANDS">SOUTH GEORGIA AND THE SOUTH SANDWICH ISLANDS</option>
<option value="SOUTH KOREA">SOUTH KOREA</option>
<option value="SPAIN">SPAIN</option>
<option value="SRI LANKA">SRI LANKA</option>
<option value="SUDAN">SUDAN</option>
<option value="SURINAME">SURINAME</option>
<option value="SVALBARD AND JAN MAYEN">SVALBARD AND JAN MAYEN</option>
<option value="SWAZILAND">SWAZILAND</option>
<option value="SWEDEN">SWEDEN</option>
<option value="SWITZERLAND">SWITZERLAND</option>
<option value="SYRIAN ARAB REPUBLIC">SYRIAN ARAB REPUBLIC</option>
<option value="TAIWAN">TAIWAN</option>
<option value="TAJIKISTAN">TAJIKISTAN</option>
<option value="TANZANIA, UNITED REPUBLIC OF">TANZANIA, UNITED REPUBLIC OF</option>
<option value="THAILAND">THAILAND</option>
<option value="TIMOR-LESTE">TIMOR-LESTE</option>
<option value="TOGO">TOGO</option>
<option value="TOKELAU">TOKELAU</option>
<option value="TONGA">TONGA</option>
<option value="TRINIDAD AND TOBAGO">TRINIDAD AND TOBAGO</option>
<option value="TUNISIA">TUNISIA</option>
<option value="TURKEY">TURKEY</option>
<option value="TURKMENISTAN">TURKMENISTAN</option>
<option value="TURKS AND CAICOS ISLANDS">TURKS AND CAICOS ISLANDS</option>
<option value="TUVALU">TUVALU</option>
<option value="UGANDA">UGANDA</option>
<option value="UKRAINE">UKRAINE</option>
<option value="UNITED ARAB EMIRATES">UNITED ARAB EMIRATES</option>
<option value="UNITED KINGDOM">UNITED KINGDOM</option>
<option value="UNITED STATES">UNITED STATES</option>
<option value="UNITED STATES MINOR OUTLYING ISLANDS">UNITED STATES MINOR OUTLYING ISLANDS</option>
<option value="URUGUAY">URUGUAY</option>
<option value="UZBEKISTAN">UZBEKISTAN</option>
<option value="VANUATU">VANUATU</option>
<option value="VENEZUELA">VENEZUELA</option>
<option value="VIETNAM">VIETNAM</option>
<option value="VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH">VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH</option>
<option value="VIRGIN ISLANDS, U.S.">VIRGIN ISLANDS, U.S.</option>
<option value="WALLIS AND FUTUNA">WALLIS AND FUTUNA</option>
<option value="WESTERN SAHARA">WESTERN SAHARA</option>
<option value="YEMEN">YEMEN</option>
<option value="ZAMBIA">ZAMBIA</option>
<option value="ZIMBABWE">ZIMBABWE</option>
</select><br></td> </tr>


</table>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```